# Thrust Cmake commands is not defined

Tags: c++, cmake, thrust

I can include the Thrust library into my project and use that, but I cannot use Thrust Cmake commands like:

```
thrust_create_target(ThrustTBB HOST TBB DEVICE CUDA)
```

Can I install the Thrust library from source? I suppose that Thrust is included in the CUDA library.

Comment: You probably need some find_package before that. However I am not familiar with this library. The documentation says yes `find_package(Thrust REQUIRED CONFIG)`: [https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/cmake/README.md](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/cmake/README.md)

Comment: I use CUDA 10.0.13. It's probably related with that. Maybe my Thrust version doesn't support those commands. Is there any way to install Thrust from source? How can I import the Thrust library into my C++ project using source files?